# Is it possible to filter google place picker

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Is it possible to filter the locations google placepicker displays for lets say only supermarkets?
Otherwise, how would i best go about creating a view like this?

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

 int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(context), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is place api rather than place picker. It supports the following categories: [**Link**](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

Comment: So add place api and search by category. Hope this gives you an idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is not currently available. You may follow these two open issues for updates:

- [Issue 8484:  Filter Place Picker by PlaceType](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8484)
- [Issue 8565:  PlacePicker Customization - Add Place Type Filter to Intent Builder](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8565)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't. I tried extend the PlacePicker class, nothing I can override. Place Picker API looks tentative, hope Google will add this feature in the future.

Answer (score -4):

You will need to add a place type in your place search, grocery_or_supermarket is one of them.

Source: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types